# Implementing fractions in python

Tags: python

I tried to implement fractions using classes in python, but when I ran it,
it showed the error 'function gcd is not defined'. I can't seem to figure out how.

However, when I defined GCD outside the class it was working perfectly fine.

```
class frac:

    def gcd(a, b):
                if(b == 0):
                    return a
                else:
                    return gcd(b, a%b)

    def __init__(self, numer, denom):

        if(denom == 0):
            raise Exception("WTF")
        else:
            self.numer = numer
            self.denom = denom
            self.ratify()



    def ratify(self):

        g = gcd(self.numer, self.denom)
        self.numer = self.numer/g
        self.denom = self.denom/g



    def add(self, b):
        n,d = self.numer, self.denom
        self.numer = n*b.denom + d*b.numer
        self.denom = d*b.denom
        self.ratify()
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but consider using the existing [Fraction](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/fractions.html) and [gcd](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/fractions.html#fractions.gcd) instead of implementing your own

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show the code that results in the error 'function gcd is not defined'. In other words, please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it is now, your code snippet is not complete. Remember to show the full traceback for the error. Also, you should be using integer division in your `ratify` function, not the floating-point division you are using now--unless you are using "legacy Python," version 2. Are you?

Answer (score 1):

Your `gcd` method needs to look like:

```py
    def gcd(self, a, b):
        if(b == 0):
            return a
         else:
            return self.gcd(b, a%b)
```

Comment: Sorry, I copied the code wrong, can you see the question again?

Comment: And the same `self` prefix will be needed in `ratify `.

Comment: I'd rather move `gcd` outside of the class scope as it never uses `self` anyway.